# Selecting the top 11 rows per person

Tags: sql

I am trying to collect the most recent 11 rows per person based on date. I have my Provider Number  Qtr, and Month. So, the result would give me the 11 most recent submissions by date per individual. I have been trying to write this in SQL but no luck.

I tried using Max, but it gave me the newest single date. Close but I wanted the newest 11 per individual.

```
Select DISTINCT 
 I.ProviderNumber as 'Provider Number', 
 I.Qtr as 'Report QTR', (Select MAX(MonthName)   
 from incentive.F_IndividualMonthSummary) as 'Month'  
From Incentives;
```

Comment: Please tage your dbms, is it `mysql` or `mssql` ...?

Comment: I am using mssq mssql. Sorry about that.

Comment: Could you please add some sample data and expected outcome? I wonder why you already got an answer since for me it's unclear what exactly you want to do. Even it the answer really solves your issue, a better description will help people who have a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
select ProviderNumber, Qtr, MonthName, 
row_number() over (partition by ProviderNumber order by MonthName desc) rownum
from F_IndividualMonthSummary
where rownum < 12
order by rownum desc
```

Comment: I think it should be `Select Top 11...`

Comment: You can't get a per person using top. You can't do this without row_number().